# Could an .htaccess affect charset options in another directory?

Tags: htaccess, cms, character-set

My company is still running a ~12 year old CMS for project management and until yesterday it was working fine.

Then I uploaded a version of Tiki Wiki CMS to complete separate folder on the same server.

That somehow triggered the old CMS to partially break down. Some functions involving stings stopped working altogether. I also noticed that suddenly special characters were not displayed correctly anymore so I guess it’s a charset issue.

So I am a bit puzzled how this could have happened.

Could the .htaccess files from the Tiki Wiki CMS somehow affect the global charset settings? I checked the local phpinfo in the old CMS directory but nothing was changed.

Comment: If the "Tiki Wiki CMS" was uploaded to an entirely separate folder then this really should not influence the rest of the server. Is there any URL rewriting? Was the .htaccess in the site root altered at all? However, a CMS usually comes with a DB and this might have done something with the DB charset? Otherwise, _something else_ was updated.